# Variable change is not getting picked up and rerendered in the template with Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a component that as a part of it renders a name of the user based on the profile object.

The corresponding part of a template is:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="userMenu" *ngIf="isAuthenticated()">
      {{profile?.name}}
    </button>
```

And the profile is getting loaded in onInit function of that component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (this.authService.userProfile) {
      this.profile = this.authService.userProfile;
    } else {
      this.authService.getProfile((err, profile) => {
        this.profile = profile;
      });
    }
  }
```

When I navigate to this page the first time, the name is not rendered, even though the `isAuthenticated` always returns `true`.

If I refresh the page, it starts rendering properly.

What am I doing wrong?

After, some more digging around, it appears that it only happens right after the authentication.

Here is the AuthService code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth(environment.auth0);

  userProfile: any;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  public login(): void {
    this.auth0.authorize();
  }

  public handleAuthentication(): void {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        window.location.hash = '';
        this.setSession(authResult);
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      } else if (err) {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }

  private setSession(authResult): void {
    // Set the time that the Access Token will expire at
    const expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);
  }

  public logout(): void {
    // Remove tokens and expiry time from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('expires_at');
    // Go back to the home route
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    // Check whether the current time is past the
    // Access Token's expiry time
    const expiresAt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'));
    return new Date().getTime() < expiresAt;
  }

  public getProfile(cb): void {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if (!accessToken) {
      throw new Error('Access Token must exist to fetch profile');
    }

    const self = this;
    this.auth0.client.userInfo(accessToken, (err, profile) => {
      if (profile) {
        self.userProfile = profile;
      }
      cb(err, profile);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have change changeDetectionStrategy ?

Comment: Please show your code for your `authService`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, what was happening is the `app-nav` was loading first in auth-callback, when the user is not logged in first. And since the component is not reloaded every time when the route changes, the component didn't get that information about logged in user, so it was stuck in that situation until reload.

The solution was to not even include navigation component on the routes that should not even expect a user to exists.